# Google play store android api?

Tags: android, android-search, google-play

In my android application, I want to show list of applications made by a specific company and exist in play store.But I  am not finding any api to perform search with some keyword.

Any web APIs are available for searching on Google Play store?

what all ways are possible to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's an unofficial API for Google Play Apps, try checking this out:

```
https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is also [42matters.com Google Play Store Android API](https://42matters.com/docs/overview?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=answer&utm_campaign=so_a) where you can fetch all the data you are searching for.

Access to the data is not free, but you can try the API with a [14 days free trial](https://42matters.com/app-market-data?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=answer&utm_campaign=so_a)